# What is the most basic "depth" of any "container file"?

Tags: filesystems, tree

I use the term "container file" to describe any file which practically contains one file or two or more files. Some examples would be a *tar archive* or a *directory*.

Let's say I open a tar archive with some archiving GUI software or let's say I open a directory with some GUI OS file browser and in both cases, indeed, one file, or two or more files which are *contained* in the container file appear before me (in the first, most basic depth - not accounting "deeper depths").

In general, what is the depth of these files, in Unix and Linux systems? Is it depth 0 or depth 1?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question I would cite the usage of depth in the `find` command. You can use the flag `--maxdepth` to define the maximum depth in which you want to look for certain files.
Now if you are in a directory (or container file to use your words, although that is usually associated with docker) with the following structure

```
.
└── dir1
    └── file1
```

(this is the output of the tree command) and run `find -maxdepth 0` you get only `.`. When you run `find -maxdepth 1` instead you get the actual content of the directory that you are in, aka `./dir1`. To continue this a search with maxdepth 2 of course also outputs `./dir1/file1` but that should already be obvious.

To sum it up, the files contained in the directory you are currently located in are at depth 1, not 0.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer; I admit I find it odd that the (tree-like) data description starts from this dot and not just from `dir1` (if the user is inside `dir1`) because I don't think it is comparable with `cd .` as it's mere data being shown, but perhaps there is some advantage I am not aware of, in this case.

Comment: @JohnDoea No, the user is not in dir1, he is in `.`. The dot basically is a synonym for current directory

Comment: Yes, I know, I confused with `cd ..`. Thanks,

Comment: @JohnDoea Now when thinking about it that way you can see why .. behaves like it does, it just means the directory that contains the current directory. I like how you ask questions that make me think about kind of basic stuff that is important in order to understand the concept of linux

Comment: thank you; this is a nice complement for me,

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be asking about terminology.  You are right to be careful, the term "depth" can be tricky and I always find myself checking my own logic before using it.

To understand why the answer is 1 (and it is 1) you have to understand that the decision to index from 0 or index from 1 isn't arbitrary.  It is actually describing two completely different things.  To explain, think of a list containing some colours [red, blue, purple].  We can talk about this list in two ways:

1. In the list: **1**st is red, **2**nd is blue, **3**rd is purple.  Clearly indexing from 1
2. Purple is **2** away from the start of the list, blue is **1** away from the start of the list, red is the start of the list - **0**. Indexing from 0.

In computer science, using an offset (indexing from 0) is preferred because it makes a lot of the maths simpler to program.  But it's important to understand we are not just "indexing from zero" we are describing something different.

Indexing from zero is (virtually) *always an offset*, even if there is a phantom zero.

---

With `find` terminology, find is indexing from 0 as an offset from the current directory.  Thus `-maxdepth 1` means start at the current directory end explore 1 layer.  Likewise `find . -maxdepth 0` is just `.` because you are starting at the current directory and expanding nothing.

Until this discussion you most likely never even considered finding depth 0.  The 0 is a phantom (no really useful).

---

Following on from there, in container terminology a depth of 0 would have to mean expanding zero zip files.  It would mean there is no container at all.  A single layer deep (a zip containing other files but no other zips) would always be depth 1 because you start outside the container and have to expand one container to extract the files.

Comment: Thanks; if I understood correctly, when a user is at depth 1 and when a user is at depth 0 depends on the utility but in general the we start from `.` which equals 0 but always expand to the border of 1, so practically a zip with regular files (say only `.md` files) is extracted from the user's place (`.=0`) to 1 ("depth 1") so we got everything in depth 1.

Comment: Yes that logic would work for most people.